# Getting javascript variable value inside html

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following piece of javascript code in my project.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    function changeval() {
        total = parseInt($("#small").val()) + parseInt($("#medium").val()) + parseInt($("#large").val()) + parseInt($("#xlarge").val()) + parseInt($("#xxlarge").val());
    }
```

How can I get the value of $total in the following code instead of 12 in the last line?

```
<tr>
    <td><b>Total</b></td>
    <td>
        <input id="total" name="total" type="number" value="1" class="form-control total input-md" disabled min=1 max=99999 />
    </td>
    <td> <div class="total-quantity" style="display:none;">12</div> </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace 12 with something like a label and give it an id. Let's call the id="totalQty".

In the Javascript $totalQty.val() = 12 or what ever you want to set it to.

Comment: Remove the inline style display none if you want to see the total ;-)

Comment: <div class="total-quantity"><label id="totalQty"></label></div>           <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#totalQty").text("12");
    });
</Script>

Comment: Thanks bilpor. Almost there. I have added the snippet like you mentioned.   $(document).ready(function() { 
            var ffvalue=  $("#totalQty").text("$total");
            alert(ffvalue);

                });  But when I alert I am not getting the value of total instead an error ' [object Object]

Comment: the text("$total") at the end is the bit giving you the error. you need to remove the " from around the $total as this makes it a literal. You probably need to change $total to be #total.val(), but from your question it will show 1 based on the value in your html to total else change the total = in your changeval func to something like $totalQty so that it doesn't get confused with the input variable declared on the page and then do text($totalQty)

Answer (score 0):

add the total to the element

```
function changeval() {
        $total = parseInt($("#small").val()) + parseInt($("#medium").val()) + parseInt($("#large").val()) + parseInt($("#xlarge").val()) + parseInt($("#xxlarge").val());
        $('.total-quantity').text($total);
}
```